# Regular Expression - Create

Tags: regex

How to validate a RegExp that contains only:

- lower case only
- no special characters and space
- allow _ (underline)
- allow - (hyphen)
- do not accept capital letters in the middle of the string

  I tried something like `/ \ A (\ w | \ d | - | _) + \ z /`

  with string character uppercase (failure)

  with string first character uppercase (failure)

Answer (score 1):

^[a-z_-]+$

^ Start matching at the beginning of the string
[] Match with this set of patterns
a-z Lowercase letters
_- Underscore and hyphen
+ Match 1 or more of the previous set
$ End match at the end

By anchoring your pattern matching between ^ and $, you'll avoid having unwanted characters in the middle without having to do anything advanced-ish like: look-ahead, look-behind. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) has a good write up, the [MSDN quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) is good too. One caveat is that regular expression grammars mostly have similarities but can be language specific, so consult documentation for the implementing language.

Comment: First thanks for the response and attention. It didn't work buddy. Would I be able to assemble according to my model explained above? thank you

Comment: What programming language are you working in? What I wrote is for Perl5 or .net.

Comment: Do you need to allow an upper case character at the beginning?

Comment: On the contrary, it is not possible to allow one more character at the beginning of the string or during it.
Example:
Signatures (failed)
TesT (failure)

Comment: ^[A-Z]?[a-z_-]+[A-Z]?$